# Why does my div positioned (absolute) over an image slide up when I shrink the screen width?

Tags: html, css, position

As I drag the right side of the window making it thinner, the div of content I positioned absolute over an image continues to slide up the page.

How do I keep the div of content still?

Comment: position: absolute is positioned based on the closest parent with position: relative, if the parent's position change, so will its. If you want it relative to window you should use position: fixed

Comment: Ah, you're right I assigned the parent position of relative to the wrong element.